# ajax form data pass before the page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use a `jQuery.get()` **request** to send a form data. But often the page `reloads/redirects` too fast, before my `JavaScript/jQuery` code catches and sends the form data to where i need. I use `alert()` to get the ajax request done while the user clicks ok on alert. Now i need the form working as usual `(with PHP post and redirect)` and to send the form data using jQuery or JavaScript `BEFORE` the page `reloads and NO alerts`. Is there any elegant way to make the page wait `until jQuery is done` with the request `(without using alert)?`

```
jQuery('#form').live('submit', function() {
    var inputValue = jQuery(this).find('#theInput').val();
    jQuery.get('http://someurl.com/order?var=' + inputValue);
    //alert('an unwanted alert');
});
```

**UPD:** I embed jQuery code through Google Tag Manager's iframe. So I can't change the way the form works. And I shouldn't prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Send data using ajax, prevent default behaviour of submit event. Then in ajax success callback, redirect/refresh current page or whatever you want to do.

Comment: jquery ajax calls are asynchronous by default. This means that while your ajax call is waiting for a responce from the server, the rest of your script is executed normaly.
You need to set asynchronous to false (read on $.ajax on jquery manual)

Comment: @andrew In this case (as for 99% of cases), you shouldn't set ajax request to sync

Comment: @A.Wolff i know. But in OP sample code i see that his problem llies in form submiting. I dont see anything wrong in doing that in form submit. Unless i am missing some obvious drawback?

Comment: @andrew Well when submiting a FORM that's quite true than that shouldn't really matter

Comment: @A. Wolff: I did try preventDefault and stopPropagation. It didn't help

Comment: I tried returning false but it prevents the php post. I do'nt need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#form').live('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour

    var inputValue = jQuery(this).find( '#theInput' ).val();
    jQuery.get('http://someurl.com/order?var=' + inputValue, function(){
          // redirect
    });
    //alert('an unwanted alert');
});
```

Comment: @chandu Your edit changed quite a lot answer, maybe OP is not using a jQuery version which support `.on()` method and BTW, you weren't delegating event here

Comment: HI @A.Wolff, Just I am talking about latest jquery libs. Not about older one.

Comment: @chandu But which jQuery version OP is using? That was my point ;)

Comment: I can't redirect in jQuery code. I don't even know how the form works. I just embed some code using Google Tag Manager's iframe

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [`done`][[http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/]](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/%5d) which could probably do what you want it to do. .done() will wait for the entire ajax to finish, and then run whatever function you call within done.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind callback to do redirect and `return false;` to prevent default redirect shown as below:

```
jQuery('#form').on('submit', function() {
    var inputValue = jQuery(this).find( '#theInput' ).val();
    jQuery.get('http://someurl.com/order?var=' + inputValue,
        function(data){
            //write redirect code here. In case if you want to check response, you can get it in data variable.
        });
    return false; //prevent default redirect action
});
```